# Is there any possibility to listen on an sql table/field with camel?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, apache-camel, osgi

I got a web service built with camel and running as an OSGi bundle on karaf.

When I get a request here I store the data from the request in a MySQL database. After this another bundle has to retrieve the data, do something with it and then update the dataset and mark it as processed in the db as soon as it is done. Then the first bundle got to retrieve the processed/changed data again the send it as a repsonse to the original request.

The problem here is that I need some kind of listener on that data in the db because the whole thing has to be as fast as possible (user is waiting for the answer).

Is there any possibility to solve this? Doing a query on the table every x seconds/milliseconds is really dirty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some examples that demonstrate this, for example using the MyBatis or SQL component

- http://camel.apache.org/mybatis-example.html
- http://camel.apache.org/sql-example.html

You can also use JPA as Christian says.

There is no special MySQL component that uses some MySQL native API for listening on events. I am not aware if there is any such API. The components in Camel are generic JDBC/SQL components that does a SQL SELECT.

Comment: would this example http://camel.apache.org/mybatis-example.html be working as a listener? or it will terminate after one run? I need to run it like WatchService , would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [camel-jpa](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html) component. You define a jpa Entity class that represents your table data. Then you start your route with from("jpa:..."). This will automatically poll the DB and send an object into the route for each entity. You can then either delete or update (@Consumed method) the table row.