# Listen insertions on a table with Camel

Tags: database, apache-camel

I have an application in Java with Spring boot 2, and I want to listen to the insertions on a table, that was made by a trigger, is mandatory that I use Camel, because it is easy to do, but I don't find the answer.

I found this but the links are broken.

[is-there-any-possibility-to-listen-on-an-sql-table-field-with-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709772/is-there-any-possibility-to-listen-on-an-sql-table-field-with-camel)

**Update and the Answer**

I got an approach, using the SQL component :
(Groovy code)

```
@Component
class PagosRouter extends RouteBuilder {

  @Autowired
  private OracleDataSource mydataSource

  @Override
  void configure() {

    String rowId = 'row-ID'

    from('sql:select * from THE_TABLE where IS_NEW = 1?dataSource=mydataSource')
        // Catch every sigle row  
        .process { exchange ->
          // Set in the header the md5 row
          exchange.in.setHeader(rowId, exchange.in.body.toString().md5())
        }
        // Set a component that filter every rowId, discarting the repeated ones
        .idempotentConsumer( header(rowId), new JdbcMessageIdRepository(mydataSource, 'theTableWatcher') )
        .split(body()).parallelProcessing(true)
        // Process the new rows 
        .process( { exchange ->
          // Do somthing here
        })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot listen on table. But you can have a camel component that periodically polls (.ie executes a query for example every 5 seconds).

For example if you have an incremental integer as primary key, and query will have a where condition with id greater than the insertions that were read last time.

Or it may depend on creationTime of the record

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sql-component.html

Comment: Yes, that was the way, I write the complete code in the updated part of the question.

Comment: And I found a custom Camel component, but it is not official, so is not a safe implementation for a productive and crucial software, but it is so interesting:

https://github.com/welshstew/camel-oraevent

Answer (score 0):

If table B is made by a trigger on table A, you can build table C from the insertions on table B using a trigger there.  You will have to poll table C with a select and delete rows already processed.  It looks like Camel can monitor table C.